# Getting error while creating an Enum with each value pointing to a list of String

Tags: java, enums, java-11

```
public enum Test implements IsSerializable {

    FOOD("FOOD", getFoodItems()),//---Getting Error here
    HOTEL("HOTEL", getHotels());//---Getting Error here

    private String name;
    static final List<String> categories = new LinkedList<String>();

    Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<String> getCategories() {
       return this.categories;
    }


    private  List<String> getFoodItems(){
       categories.add("Food item1");
       categories.add("Food item2");
       return categories;
    }
    private  List<String> getHotels(){
       categories.add("Hotel 1");
       categories.add("Hotel 2");
       return categories;
    }
}
```

I am getting error while creating this Enum. I am new to this type Enum . Can anyone help to make this work?

Comment: Tried with static methods also. Getting the same.

Comment: Your constructor only takes one argument but you are passing two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 3 main things:

#### 1. `getFoodItems()` and `getHotels()` should be static.

The methods need the existing enum to exist and do not even use anything in the enum.

#### 2. don't declare `categories` as a static attribute..

You use the same `categories` object(or references to the same object) because it is static. Remove the `static` keyword before it in order to make it a member attribute. Each object should have it's own list and this is not possible if it is `static`.

#### 3. create the List inside the method and give it to the constructor

You call the constructor with 2 parameters: the name and the List but the constructor does only accept the name. Create the `categories` object inside the methand and return it to the constructor.

## 3 additional improvements from @[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) (see the comments)

#### 4. Think twice before handing out references to mutable lists.

If you pass a mutable list to a method, that method can change the list which could lead to bugs that may be difficult to find.

#### 5. The `name` is entirely obsolete as there is no getter for it and its value matches the intrinsic `name()` anyway.

You may want to add it in any case but enumerations already have a method `name()` that returns the name of the enum.

#### 6. Don’t use `LinkedList` when you don’t need its special features (in other words, never use it), but rather, use an `ArrayList` or even better, `List.of(item1, item2)`, to create an immutable list.

`ArrayList` is more performant that `LinkedList` in general because it is based on an array and `LinkedList` is a linked list(as the name says) that has to create an object for every element containing reference to it's neighbours. That is an advantage if you need to add elements in the middle (or the start) of the list or if you need `Queue` or `Dequeue` functionality.

```
public enum Test implements IsSerializable {
    FOOD("FOOD",getFoodItems()),//---Getting Error here.
    HOTEL("HOTEL",getHotels());//---Getting Error here
    private String name;
    private final List<String> categories;
    private Test(String name,List<String> categories) {
        this.name = name;
        this.categories=categories;
    }
    public List<String> getCategories() {
        return this.categories;
    }
    private static List<String> getFoodItems(){
        List<String> categories = new LinkedList<>();
        categories.add("Food item1");
        categories.add("Food item2");
        return categories;
    }
    private static List<String> getHotels(){
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add("Hotel 1");
        categories.add("Hotel 2");
        return categories;
     }
}
```

​

[**Edit**]
Please also take note of the answer from [boot-and-bottet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5860073/boot-and-bonnet)

Comment: 4. Think twice before handing out references to mutable lists. 5. The `name` is entirely obsolete as there is no getter for it and its value matches the intrinsic `name()` anyway. 6. Don’t use `LinkedList` when you don’t need its special features (in other words, never use it), but rather, use an `ArrayList` or even better, `List.of(item1, item2)`, to create an immutable list.

Comment: @Holger You're right. I've added this to my answer - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Static methods should work, if the constructor is fixed. If the list of items is small, why not declare them inline?

```java
    public static enum Test implements IsSerializable {
        FOOD("FOOD", "Food item1", "Food item2"),
        HOTEL("HOTEL", "Hotel 1", "Hotel 2");

        private final String displayName;
        private final List<String> categories;

        Test(String displayName, String... categories) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
            this.categories = List.of(categories);
        }

        public String displayName() {
            return displayName;
        }

        public List<String> getCategories() {
            return categories;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Core issue is that enum initialized in static, and from that context you can't reference non-static items (fields, methods).

Also you don't have place for those lists in your enum - constructor accepts only `name` param.

You could try to use List.of("Food item1", "Food item2") instead for example and adding new field.